# join() array wrapping each value with backtick signs

Tags: php

How to join array data wrapping each value with [backtick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtick) signs?

One-line solution needed without changing array itself.

```
$coldata = array('value1','value2','value3');
$joined_coldata = join(', ', $coldata);
```

Expected result:

```
`value1`, `value2`, `value3`
```

Comment: Consider using `implode` instead of `join`. The latter is an alias which easily leads people to believe that using `split` to do the reverse thing is acceptable (hint: it is not. the reverse is `explode()`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$joined_coldata = empty($coldata)?"":"`".implode('`, `', $coldata)."`";
```

This implodes the string with backticks around every concatenation (join is an alias of implode) and adds backticks around the result which looks after imploding like:

```
value1`, `value2`, ..., `valueN
```

And checks additionally if it was empty: Then it outputs nothing instead of two backticks.

Comment: Great! Empty check is definitely needed.

Comment: And looks prettier this way: `$joined_coldata = empty($coldata) ? '': '\`' . implode('\`, \`', $coldata) . '\`';`

Comment: @Radio This is subjective, the one may find it more readable with as much whitespaces, the other with less.

Comment: Not more whitespaces than doublequotes. =)

Answer (score 3):

Here's the "cheap" way:

```
$joined_coldata = "`".implode("`, `",$coldata)."`";
```

And the "proper" way (expanded onto seveal lines, but all one "line" of code):

```
$joined_coldata = implode(",",array_map(function($a) {
    // perform escaping here
    return "`".$a."`";
},$coldata));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$coldata = array('value1','value2','value3');
$joined_coldata = "'" . join("','", $coldata) . "'";
```

Should do the trick

Comment: Backtick needed, not Apostrophe =))

Comment: @Radio Then simply replace the backtick by an apostrophe here...

Comment: I was about to answer that, but anyway there are better answers to the question...

Answer (score 1):

Not pretty but this is the easiest way:

```
$joined_coldata = '`' . join('`, `', $coldata) . '`';
```

Make sure that `$coldata` is not empty though - if it is, you need to handle it separately to avoid getting a single empty element!